# Will Roslyn be able to parse and compile F# code?

Tags: f#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

The `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageNames` class has an entry for F#:

```
public static class LanguageNames
{
    public const string CSharp = "C#";
    public const string VisualBasic = "Visual Basic";
    public const string FSharp = "F#";
}
```

This got me excited, I thought I could let my users also use F# just by toggling one property. Alas, it doesn't seem to be the case. There are Roslyn nuget packages for C# and VB.NET but nothing for F#.

Is support for analyzing and running F# code planned in Roslyn?

If not, what alternatives would you recommend for parsing and executing F#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [F# Compiler Service](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/).

The problem with F# on Roslyn is that F# has been self-hosted from the very start, while C# and VB compilers were written in C++ for a long time. By the time C# and VB finally grew up and got Roslyn, F# already had a well developed compiler with its own architecture. Worse, that architecture could not be easily followed in Roslyn (though I think they didn't even try), because it makes heavy use of language features not available in C# and VB.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 | File not found"*.

Comment: This might be the correct link https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-compiler-docs/fcs/